# How can I insert 'string' in HTML body?

Tags: html, ruby, string

I am trying to get any HTML and insert specific strings to the body.

This is part of my script:

```
  orig_comments = defect.Field(@td_columns[:"Comments"])      
  line_comments = "________________________________________"
  reopened_comments = "reopened"  
  reason_comments = "reason"      

  new_comments = "#{orig_comments}\n#{line_comments}\n#{reopened_comments}\n#{reason_comments}\n"
  new_comments.gsub(/\n/, '<br>')
```

`orig_comments` is the HTML format:

```
<html>
<body>
<div align="left"><font face="Arial"><span style="font-size:9pt">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></font></div>
<div align="left"><font face="Arial" color="#000080" size="1"><span style="font-size:8pt"><b>Hello&lt;hello.hello&gt;, 
2015-02-05:</b></span></font><font face="Arial"><span style="font-size:9pt"> </span></font></div>
<div align="left"><font face="Arial"><span style="font-size:9pt">1st line</span></font></div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I simply append `line_comments`, `reopend_comments` and `reason_comments` to the `orig_comments`, the result in the HTML view is:

```
Hello<hello.hello>, 2015-02-05: 
1st line
________________________________________ reopened
```

I cannot see 'reason' comments and proper new lines.

Could you let me know how I can insert a newline and other strings in this case?

**UPDATE**

I implemented the scripts that I wanted and It is working well.

Additionally, I have one more question.

When I append a new child, I want to use variable in the value.

For example,

```
date=Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") 

tmp1 = '<div align="left"><font face="Arial"><span style="font-size:9pt">#{date}</span></font></div>'
```

But, 'date' variable is not displayed as I expect. 'variable' is not working.

Could you let me get any advice?

**modified scripts**

```
  orig_html = defect.Field(@td_columns[:"Comments"])
  #XML module only provides html parsing without the DOCTYPE tag.
  doc = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(orig_html)  

  tmp1 = '<div align="left"><font face="Arial"><span style="font-size:9pt">________________________________________</span></font></div>'
  tmp2 = '<div align="left"><font face="Arial"><span style="font-size:9pt">This issue has been reopend. please, check it again referring following one of the reasons.</span></font></div>'
  tmp3 = '<div align="left"><font face="Arial"><span style="font-size:9pt">&lt;reopen reasons&gt;</span></font></div>'
  tmp4 = '<div align="left"><font face="Arial"><span style="font-size:9pt">1. This issue may have reoccur in the latest source codes.</span></font></div>'
  tmp5 = '<div align="left"><font face="Arial"><span style="font-size:9pt">2. The commit may not have been applied.</span></font></div>'
  tmp6 = '<div align="left"><font face="Arial"><span style="font-size:9pt">3. This issue may not have been fixed in the right way.</span></font></div>'
  tmp7 = '<div align="left"><font face="Arial"><span style="font-size:9pt">4. The tool may not have recognized your well-modified source codes.</span></font></div>'
  child1 = Nokogiri::XML::fragment(tmp1)
  child2 = Nokogiri::XML::fragment(tmp2)
  child3 = Nokogiri::XML::fragment(tmp3)
  child4 = Nokogiri::XML::fragment(tmp4)
  child5 = Nokogiri::XML::fragment(tmp5)
  child6 = Nokogiri::XML::fragment(tmp6)
  child7 = Nokogiri::XML::fragment(tmp7)
  body = doc.at('body')
  body.add_child(child1)
  body.add_child(child2)
  body.add_child(child3)
  body.add_child(child4)
  body.add_child(child5)
  body.add_child(child6)
  body.add_child(child7)
```

Comment: You shouldn't try to manipulate HTML using regular expressions. While it might be possible to get it to work, it will be very fragile. Instead, learn to use a HTML/XML parser, like [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org), which is the de facto standard for Ruby. You can't simply append to a HTML document. The closing `</html>` tag marks the end of the document. Instead, you need to search for the place *inside* the `<html><body>` block where you want to insert the new content, and do it there. I suggest you learn more about how HTML is structured, then study how to use Nokogiri.

Comment: I've installed Nokogiri. and I will study it more. Thanks for your advice @the Tin Man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty example of how to manipulate your HTML:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
<body>
<div align="left"><font face="Arial"><span style="font-size:9pt">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></font></div>
<div align="left"><font face="Arial" color="#000080" size="1"><span style="font-size:8pt"><b>Hello&lt;hello.hello&gt;, 
2015-02-05:</b></span></font><font face="Arial"><span style="font-size:9pt"> </span></font></div>
<div align="left"><font face="Arial"><span style="font-size:9pt">1st line</span></font></div>
</body>
</html>
EOT

body = doc.at('body')

body.add_child(
  [
    '________________________________________', 
    'reopened', 
    'reason'
  ].join("<br>\n")
)

puts doc.to_html
# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# >> <html>
# >> <body>
# >> <div align="left"><font face="Arial"><span style="font-size:9pt">&#160;&#160;</span></font></div>
# >> <div align="left">
# >> <font face="Arial" color="#000080" size="1"><span style="font-size:8pt"><b>Hello&lt;hello.hello&gt;, 
# >> 2015-02-05:</b></span></font><font face="Arial"><span style="font-size:9pt"> </span></font>
# >> </div>
# >> <div align="left"><font face="Arial"><span style="font-size:9pt">1st line</span></font></div>
# >> ________________________________________<br>
# >> reopened<br>
# >> reason</body>
# >> </html>
```

Nokogiri is very flexible and makes it easy to modify HTML and XML. The trick is to find the Node you want and then manipulate it, or maybe the ones around it if the node is just a landmark.

The `at('body')` method searches for the first `body` tag and returns it as a [Nokogiri::XML::Node](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node). Once I have that I can modify it or its children easily.

`add_child` can take several different types of parameters, but the easiest thing to pass it is a string containing the HTML you want to add. In this case I created three strings in an array, used `join` to append them together with an intervening `<br>\n`, and appended them as the last child of the `<body>` tag.